# Avoid repeated post on page 2 when excluding one on page 1

Tags: wp-query, pagination, exclude

On the site we're developing, infinite scrolling is activated by Ajax/JavaScript.

```
$('#inifiniteLoader').show('fast');
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php bloginfo('wpurl') ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    type:'POST',
    data: "action=infinite_scroll&cat='<?php echo $cat_id ?>'&exclude='<?php 
        echo get_the_ID() ?>'&page_no="+ pageNumber + '&loop_file=loop', 
    success: function(html){
        $('#inifiniteLoader').hide('1000');
        $("#primary").append(html); // This will be the div where our content will be loaded
    }
});
```

On the site as a whole this works, but on the single page, where the post is displayed and then all the other posts in that category (except the post) as thumbnails, there is a problem.

The `WP_Query` is excluding the post in question:

```
$args = array ( 'cat' => $catId, 'post__not_in' => $postid );
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

This also works, but the pagination doesn't.

Example: [Listing of professors](http://www.architektur-hochschule-trier.eu/category/lehrende/profs/)

The grid is supposed to show 8 thumbs a page. The 3 on the bottom form page 2.
When you click on a thumbnail and enter the post, the thumbs (except the current) are repeated. As you can see, something goes wrong with the pagination because the current is excluded, the first page shows one from page 2. And this is then the first post on page 2, resulting in double posts.

If I change the `loop.php` to skip the first post, only seven are shown and the grid is not filled.

The query in the functions looks like this, and also excludes the current post:

```
function wp_infinitepaginate() {
    $loopFile       = $_POST['loop_file'];
    $paged          = $_POST['page_no'];
    $cats           = $_POST['cat'];
    $exclude        = $_POST['exclude'];
    $posts_per_page = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );

    $showposts = $posts_per_page;
    $offset = ( ( $showposts * $paged ) - $showposts );

    $args = array(
        'cat'            => $cats,
        'posts_per_page' => $showposts,
        'offset'         => $offset,
        'post__not_in'   => array( $exclude ),
    );

    # Load the posts
    //query_posts( array( 'paged' => $paged ) );
    query_posts( $args );

    get_template_part( $loopFile );

    wp_reset_query();   
    exit;
}
```

Any tips?

Comment: Can you post the PHP AJAX handler for `infinite_scroll`

Comment: Make sure that the exclude ID passed to the AJAX handler is the ID of the first post and not the main page (`get_the_ID()` may well be printing the ID of the page).

Comment: I discovered that it works if I write the number of the post in the AJAX handler manually: 'post__not_in' => array(3067),  So either the handler doesn't retrieve the correct exclude ID or the formatting 'post__not_in' => array($exclude), is wrong?

Comment: What's wrong is the arguments *sent* to the AJAX handler - i.e. the `<?php echo get_the_ID() ?>` part.

Comment: but if I look at the html-source it for instance says:  data: "action=infinite_scroll&cat='42'&exclude='3067'&page_no="+ pageNumber + '&loop_file=loop', and this is the correct id, so this is what AJAX should see? it is the correct id.

Comment: do I need to register the ajax variables somewhere? I added "exclude" today in functions.php but nowhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got single quotes inside your parameter string - use an object instead for clarity:

```
$.ajax({
    data: {
        action: "infinite_scroll",
        cat: "<?php echo $cat_id ?>",
        exclude: "<?php the_ID() ?>",
        page_no: pageNumber,
        loop_file: "loop"
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks. I removed the single quotes in my parameter string, so it reads ... &exclude=<?php echo get_the_ID() ?>& ... I guess the parameter came in as a String and therefore the array did not consist of the needed numbers.